# Does a bulb offer still offer resistance even after it gets fused?

Tags: electric-circuits, electricity, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

Sorry, for my naivety this is my first time posting here.
But, my question is that will the bulb offer any resistance after it's fused?
I know that no current can flow though the fused bulb i.e. $I=0$. That makes $R = V/0$ undefined.

And voltage and total resistance stay the same, right?
So, shouldn't the rest of the bulbs in the circuit get brighter? But that isn't the case and it turns out that the potential difference of the circuit decreases (to nullify the voltage increase on the other bulbs).

I'm very confused here, please help. Thank you.

Comment: @my2cts If the bulb is broken, then $R=\infty$, not zero. Zero resistance is a completed current path, e.g., a superconducting wire.

Comment: What do you mean by "fused?" Do you mean a broken filament (in the case of an incandescent bulb)? Fused usually means one has placed a fuse device in the circuit, or one has joined two objects permanently,, similar to welding or soldering.

Comment: I have no clue what your circuit is but a broken bulb has R=$\infty$. If all the lights go out probably the whole circuit has R=$\infty$, possibly because of a blown fuse.

Comment: Your question lacks clarity in the sense that you talk about circuits but don't give any details about it.